# Server overload due to multiple xhr requests

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, unix

Recently L started experiencing performance issues with my online application hosted on bluehost.

I have an online form that takes a company name and event handler "onKeyUp" tied up to that field. Every time you put a character into the field it sends request to server which makes multiple mysql queries to get the data. Mysql queries all together take about 1-2 seconds. But since requests are send after every character that is put in it easily overloads the server.

The solution for this problem was to cancel previous XHR request before sending a new one. And it seemed to work fine for me (for about a year) until today. Not sure if bluehost changed any configuration on server (I have VPS), or any php/apache settings, but right now my application is very slow due to the amount of users i have.

And i would understand gradual decrease in productivity that may be caused bu database grow, but it suddenly happened over the weekend and speeds went down like 10 times. usual request that took about 1-2 seconds before now takes 10-16 seconds.

I connected to server via SSH & ran some stress test sending lots of queries to see what process monitor (top) will show. And as I expected, for every new request it was a php process created that was put in queue for processing. This queue waiting, apparently, took the most of wait-time.

Now I'm confused, is it possible that before (hypothetical changes on server) every XHR Abort command was actually causing PHP process to quit, reducing additional load on server, and therefore making it work faster? And now for some reason this doesn't work anymore?

I have WAMP installed on Windows 7, as my test environment, and when I export the same database and run the stress-test locally it works fast. Just like it used to be on server before. But on windows I dont have such handy process monitor as TOP, so i cannot see if php processes are actually created and killed respectively.

Not sure how to do the troubleshooting at this point.

Comment: Possible side effect of a design that doesn't scale well.  Some things to consider: make sure the xhr lookups use indexes/fulltext searches; cache the db results from individual looks if possible to reduce database load; implement a small client side delay on the lookup so multiple key inputs don't trigger multiple xhr's; make sure your web server is configured with the most efficient mpm for your environment; 1-2 seconds for a request is pretty bad to begin with, with the proper caching and db optimization this should be less than 0.5s depending on what you're looking up.

Comment: Other than advice from drew010, I would venture to say the connections may be throttled by Bluehost, even on a VPS. I've seen other hosts do this, even on an "unlimited" plan.